# Count of distinct observations per month in R

Tags: r, count

I have a data frame as below (simplified for the question).
I want to create a table in R to count the number of observations per "Month-Year". I can create it in Excel with Pivot table but not able to find a solution in R.

[image: Data Frame with the the observation ID and when it was opened at]

```
number      opened_at
YHGYA8A6Y8  07/11/2022
YHGYA8A6YA  07/11/2022
YHGYA842AZ  26/10/2022
YHGYA842AY  26/10/2022
YHGYA7Y4Z7  27/09/2022
YHGYA7Y4Z8  27/09/2022
YHGYA6Z284  31/08/2022
YHGYA6Z285  31/08/2022
YHGYA46Y23  29/07/2022
YHGYA46Y24  29/07/2022
YHGYA33443  29/06/2022
YHGYA33444  29/06/2022
YHGYA2Z8Z7  31/05/2022
YHGYA2Z8Z8  31/05/2022
YHGYAZ57YA  27/04/2022
YHGYAZ572Z  27/04/2022
YHGY8A326A  29/03/2022
YHGY8A327Z  29/03/2022
YHGY875723  20/02/2022
YHGY875724  20/02/2022
YHGY865563  28/01/2022
YHGY865564  28/01/2022
```

[image: Summary table created in Excel]

Comment: Please don't share data as an image. If you have a dataframe in R, use dput(the_name_of_your_df) and paste the output here so people can reproduce your data.

Comment: `library(zoo); table(as.yearmon(DF$opened_at, "%d/%m/%Y"))`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Also good to learn about the dput(the_name_of_your_df).